# Hovering over div and adding HTML/CSS is breaking the flow of my page

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my div JS inserts new html, but it breaks the flow in my page. I think it is the css margin in my title class, but I want the title to be centered. What is the best way to fix this?

```
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: snow;
    margin-top: 23%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/lee45276/t8xfto77/

Comment: hi dude in which way it brakes your idea.? can you explain please so i can help

Answer (score 2):

Just add vertical-align: top:

```
  .project {
        //your stuff
        vertical-align: top;
  }
```

Here is the fiddle working:

http://jsfiddle.net/t8xfto77/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this css will work for you:

```
/************
INFO
************/

.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: snow;
     position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
       -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
           transform: translateY(-50%);

}
```